# Selenium - WebDriver ignores command because browser is busy/command executes too fast

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing something like this in Java Selenium (Numbers within parenthesis are line numbers. They are not in the actual code.)

```
    (1) driver.get(URL1);
    (2) driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
    (3) WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    (4) wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete"));
    (5) driver.get(URL2);
```

But 5 `driver.get(URL2);` is ignored when executing this code but if I step (debug) through these lines it works fine.

I added two lines like this

```
    System.out.println(new Date());
```

before 3 and after 4 and the result was weird:

When running the program "normal" these printouts always return at the same time. In other words, the `wait` is returning within 1 second. However, when debugging and stepping through these lines, there is a 4-5 second long delay between these timestamps, even if I step as fast as I can.

**I suspect that 3-4 that is supposed to verify that the page has loaded are executed so fast so that they check the state of the previous (current) page (URL1) rather than waiting for the page resulting from the click. And then the browser is busy loading a new page and therefore can't handle the command sent in 5.**

**How do I fix this?**

I have read dozens of questions here on SE on how to make Selenium wait for a page to load but I am already using one of the most common solutions (line 3-4) suggested in these questions.

Comment: Why are you waiting on document.readyState== complete? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The reason for this is likely because of asychonus calls that the page is waiting for. The inital load of the page marks the state as complete, then the calls fire, causing the state to not be complete. It's a race, essentially.

Comment: @DMart The `click` is on a login button. I am loading a page, entering some login information, clicking to login and when the login is successful, I want to load another page (not the landing page you get after logging in).

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DMart What is unclear? Load page A - login - load page B.

Comment: What are the two URLs you're trying to load?

Comment: https://archive.org/account/login and https://web.archive.org/save/

Comment: @DMart See above.

Comment: I don't have a login for that site. I think something is going wrong with your login action. I would post the actual code here. Othewise I think your wait condition is still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Selenium and Web driver in Python for some time. I have just used the delay() method in Python for a rest. Can you upload the whole code or something to try to find out how to help you? Thanks!